# Removing hotwater baseboard heater

Tags: water-circulating-heating

I would like to remove the wallplate of my baseboard hotwater heater element. I got everything apart except the wallplate which I can't get off. I removed the nails that I thought were the only thing that was holding it up but it's not moving....any ideas? The house was built in the 50's.

Answer (score 1):

I ran a saw blade behind the wallplate and found a couple more nails that were hidden by the pipe and fins. After removing all the holders, I was able to lift the pipe up enough to get to the nails.